# LimitedReader reads only once

Tags: go, interface, io, reader

I'm trying to understand Go by studying [gopl book](http://www.gopl.io/). I'm stuck when trying to implement the `LimitReader` function. I realized that I have two problems so let me separate them.

**First issue**

The description from [official doc](https://pkg.go.dev/io#LimitedReader) is saying that:

> A LimitedReader reads from R but limits the amount of data returned to just N bytes. Each call to Read updates N to reflect the new amount remaining. Read returns EOF when N <= 0 or when the underlying R returns EOF.

OK, so my understanding is that I can read from `io.Reader` type many times but I will be always limited to `N` bytes. Running this code shows me something different:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    r := strings.NewReader("some io.Reader stream to be read\n")
    lr := io.LimitReader(r, 4)
    b := make([]byte, 7)
    n, err := lr.Read(b)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Read %d bytes: %s\n", n, b)

    b = make([]byte, 5)
    n, _ = lr.Read(b)
    // If removed because EOF
    fmt.Printf("Read %d bytes: %s\n", n, b)
}
// Output:

// Read 4 bytes: some
// Read 0 bytes:
// I expect next 4 bytes instead
```

It seems that this type of object is able to read only once. Not quite sure but maybe this [line in io.go](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/io/io.go#L478) source code could be changed to `l.N = 0`. The main question is why this code is inconsistent with doc description?

**Second issue**

When I've struggled with the first issue I was trying to display current `N` value. If I put `fmt.Println(lr.N)` to the code above it cannot be compiled `lr.N undefined (type io.Reader has no field or method N)`. I realized that I still don't understand Go interfaces concept.

Here is my POV (based on listing above). Using `io.LimitReader` function I create `LimitedReader` object (see [source code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/io/io.go#L459)). Due to the fact that this object contains `Read` method with proper signature its interface type is `io.Reader`. That's is the reason why `io.LimitReader` returns `io.Reader`, right? OK, so everything works together.

The question is: why `lr.N` cannot be accessed? As I correctly understood the book, interface type only requires that data type contains some method(s). Nothing more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LimitedReader` limits the total size of data that can be read, not the amount of data that can be read at each read call. That is, if you set the limit to 4, you can perform 4 reads of 1 byte, or 1 read of 4 bytes, and after that, all reads will fail.

For your second question: `lr` is an `io.Reader`, so you cannot read `lr.N`. However, you can access the underlying concrete type using a type assertion: `lr.(*io.LimitedReader).N` should work.